# Advice on Windows 7 Host and Ubuntu Guest - from WAMP

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have been using WAMP for a while on windows and I thought it was about time I moved over to a full server environment on linux. I chose ubuntu and I have installed and configured as a virtual machine (using VirtualBox).

However, I am moving from WAMP and I have 1 serious issue:

In WAMP I could simply go to c:\wamp\www and edit files directly. With my virtual machine I now have to upload files to this 'virtual' server. VirtualBox uses .vdi for the disk (which I barely understand) and I've found a single product which might mount this.

Would that be a satisfactory solution? Is there a better way of doing this?

I have tried to configure shared folders via VirtualBox but my take is that this is only reliable for sharing from host >> guest, and not guest >> host.

Is there any other virtual machine software which can effectively allow me to migrate quite easily from WAMP to ubuntu?

Appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this guide may be what you're looking for: [VirtualBox Shared Folders in Ubuntu 10.10 Guest with Windows 7 Host](http://www.sysprobs.com/virtualbox-shared-folders-ubuntu-1010-guest-windows-7-host)

Comment: that only allows me to access files from the host, on guest. I need to access files on guest, from host. Do you know how to do that? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Ah. Have you tried to access the files on guest via sftp on host using an application like [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/)? You will have to [enable ssh](http://www.unixtutorial.org/2009/05/ubuntu-ssh-how-to-enable-secure-shell-in-ubuntu/) if it is not installed/enabled by default.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but did you read my post properly? I said that the current way is to upload to the 'virtual' server. However, with wamp, I can just access files directly from my hard disk. I can't upload every time I make a change. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. However, I don't think you have to upload everytime a change is made. When editing files via FileZilla, it will automatically upload on save. You could also look into setting up a Samba share to access the files directly in Windows.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have details on how I would setup a samba share? Editing files directly in filezilla would not suffice as I will be using an IDE within my host environment to access files from guest.